# How do I redirect to different backend server based on URL using Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ip, redirect, url

I'm a newbie to Apache, sorry if this is a documented solution somewhere.  I have been scouring the web and can't seem to find this answer ...

I would like to redirect traffic based on the URL coming into my Debian Wheezy web server running Apapche to different backend servers.  For example, if the URL is http://abc.mydomain.com it will be passed on to server IP 192.168.0.100, but if the URL is http://def.mydomain.com it will be passed to server IP 192.168.0.110.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your `Apache` frontend Server as a reverse proxy for your backend servers : [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_proxy.html)

e.g :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName abc.mydomain.com
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.100
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.100
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName def.mydomain.com
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.110
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.110
</VirtualHost>
```

You will have to enable these modules :

```
a2enmod proxy 
a2enmod proxy_http
```

The advantage of `mod_proxy` is that it is transparent for the end-user : the URL in the address bar of their browser will stay unchanged : it will remain `http://abc.mydomain.com` but in fact they are served by `http://192.168.0.100`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called Reverse Proxy. Alternatively you can use Nginx which outperforms Apache as a reverse proxy.